# Problem when generating an angular project

Tags: angular-cli

I'm working in a project whith the team and it is working fine in all computres expect mine!
This is the error when launching ng serve :

```
Cannot find module 'debug'
Error: Cannot find module 'debug'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Front\node_modules\snapdragon\lib\compiler.js:5:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

Well this module "debug" dont exist in our project
but I tried to follow the error and i installed this module and then it demands 2 other modules i installed them too and launched cleanly the project but with many errors when browsing !!!

Comment: can you share package.json file?

Comment: you tried to make npm install before running the server ?

Comment: Here is the file  https://gofile.io/?c=k0cEU8

Comment: @tcharaf well i already tied to run npm install but because it is a big project with many modules added this ruined it all